# Looking for API communication methods (SOAP, Rest ...)

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest, soap

First of all i'm sorry for my bad english (i'm from Holland)

For an research i'm looking for some communication "protocols" for an web API.
I know 2 of this "protocols", REST and SOAP.

Are there some others? (i can't find some), i found WCF but this is also based on SOAP or are i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For an research i'm looking for some communication "protocols" for an
>   web API

For a web API you are restricted to protocols which use HTTP as a transport mechanism.

> I know 2 of this "protocols", REST and SOAP.

Of the two protocols you have identified, REST does not strictly qualify as a protocol, but is more of a convetion-based architectural style based on HTTP.

SOAP is a protocol with it's [two](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/) [versions](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-soap12-20010709/) formally defined.

> Are there some others?

Other, older web API protocols include [XML-RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC), which is still in (very infrequent) use, and it's newer but equally unused cousin [JSON-RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC).

A difinitive list can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_protocols).

> i found WCF but this is also based on SOAP or are i'm wrong?

WCF is not a protocol, but a communications framework for the Microsoft stack supporting sockets, message queueing, POX, REST, and of course SOAP 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation this was where i looking for